# Get Executing Path of C# application when using nunit with Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, windows, testcase

I use Jenkins, for building, unit testing, and publishing a windows application in c#.
While executing test cases using nunit-console.exe, some of them needs Application.Executing Path for completing the test case.
And it returns, nunit-console.exe path as result. Hence these test cases getting failed. ( What i need here is C# application executing path)
How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

returns the current working directory.